# Replace statement - Escape character issue in DB2

Tags: sql, replace, escaping, db2

Hi I have rows in COLUMN1:

```
C:\DOCLINKS\ATTACHMENTS\test.txt
C:\DOCLINKS\ATTACHMENTS\uvac1.jpg
C:\DOCLINKS\ATTACHMENTS\imopact.txt
```

and many other rows...

I wish to replace string `C:\DOCLINKS\ATTACHMENTS\`  with `/shared/doclinks/attachments/`

So the result should be:

```
/shared/doclinks/attachments/test.txt
/shared/doclinks/attachments/uvac1.jpg
/shared/doclinks/attachments/imopact.txt
```

This cannot work:

```
update  docinfo 
set COLUMN1 = replace('%C:\DOCLINKS\ATTACHMENTS\%', 'C:\DOCLINKS\ATTACHMENTS\', '/shared/doclinks/attachments/')
```

How to escape withing the replace statement?
I tried with:

```
'\\%' escape '\'
```

and with

```
'%\\%'
```

But nothing works.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably it is the program where you are executing the command from. I execute the following from the db2clp, and it works:

```
db2 "update paths set path = replace (path, 'C:\DOCLINKS\ATTACHMENTS\','/shared/doclinks/attachments/')"
```

Probably, your issue is the way how you call the replace function. The source string is just the column name. It is not a "like" clause.

Comment: thank you yes now and my first command works. I do not know why it did not work from DB Visualizer tool (I always do statements from there) but from clp it works...very strange but it works